Choosing Signs in Dirichlet Series to Achieve All Complex Values on the Critical Line
I'm trying to prove that for the series
$$
f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon_n}{n^s}
$$
where $\varepsilon_n = \pm 1$, we can pick the signs so that $f(s)$ approaches any complex value when $s$ is on the critical line $\operatorname{Re}(s) = 1$
In other words, for every $\xi$ with $\operatorname{Re}(\xi) = 1$ and any complex number $z$, can we find a sequence $s_n \to \xi$ (with $\operatorname{Re}(s_n) > 1$) such that $f(s_n) \to z$?
Attempt:
So, here’s my thought process. First, I know that this series converges for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$, which is a good start. I thought, okay, maybe I could just choose all $\varepsilon_n = +1$ to get the Riemann zeta function. But that doesn’t help because $\zeta(s)$ has a pretty specific range of values and doesn’t cover everything on the critical line.
Then I considered using alternating signs, but I’m not really sure how that would work out either. My intuition is that the sums could get close to any number, but I can’t figure out how to make that rigorous.
I also read something about the denseness of certain sequences, but I’m struggling to tie that back to my series.
Honestly, I feel like I’m missing something big here, or maybe I’m just overcomplicating it.

Maybe have a look at the proof of Riemann’s theorem for conditionally convergent series?

Why do you think this is true?

One hazard: For $s = 1$, $f(s)$ is real.  Let $z$ be the complex value you want to approach.  Are $z$ and $s$ fixed, then you have to exhibit choices of $\varepsilon_n$? or is $z$ fixed, then you have to exhibit choices of $s$ and $\varepsilon_n$?
